# How to check answers and change colors of radio buttons on right and wrong selection in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter app development. I have a issue in radio buttons. i have created a logic that works with flatButtons fine but i want to use this login with radio buttons. But my login gives me error that function name can't be assigned to function expressions. 
Here is the image screenshot of error.
[image]

Material Button COde:

```
Widget choicebutton(String option, String k) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  child: MaterialButton(

      //  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
      onPressed: () => checkanswer(k),
  child:  Text(
    mydata[1][i.toString()][k],
  //  textDirection:TextDirection.ltr,
    //textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    style: TextStyle(
  fontFamily: "Alike",
  fontSize: 16.0,
  color: Colors.white,
    ),
       //   maxLines: 1,
  ),
       // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 2.0, 50.0, 50.0),
      color: btncolor[k],
      splashColor: Colors.indigo[700],
      highlightColor: Colors.indigo[700],
        minWidth: 320.0,
        height: 90.0,
      shape:
      RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),


  ),
);
```

}

```
 btncolor["a"] = Colors.indigo;
  btncolor["b"] = Colors.indigo;
  btncolor["c"] = Colors.indigo;
  btncolor["d"] = Colors.indigo;

 void checkanswer(String k) {

if (mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()][k]) {
  marks = marks + 1;
  colortoshow = right;
} else {
  colortoshow = wrong;
}
setState(() {
  btncolor[k] = colortoshow;
  canceltimer = true;
});
Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), nextquestion);
```

}

Widget Code:

```
Widget radioButton( k){
return RadioListTile(
value: 1, 
groupValue:  k ,
onChanged: (value){
  checkanswer(k);
 // btncolor[k];
},
title: Text(mydata[1][i.toString()][k],
style: TextStyle(
  fontFamily: "Roboto",
  fontSize: 18.0,
),
),
activeColor:  btncolor[k],
);
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when passing functions as paramters you don't put the function name

For example

```
 Widget radioBtn(){
    return Radio(
      value: null,
      groupValue: null,
      onChanged: (value){

      },
    );
  }
```

If you however want to pass the function name, consider doing something like this

```
  Widget radioBtn(){
    return Radio(
      value: null,
      groupValue: null,
      onChanged: whenRadioButtonChanges,
    );
  }

  void whenRadioButtonChanges(value){

  }
```

Hoep this helps you.

Comment: But this is not working for me. Because logic doesn't work with the name of function.

Comment: I just updated the question with the code. I want to show colors on pressed.

Comment: "I want to show colors on pressed" can you elaborate, please? Show colors where?

Comment: When i click on radio button, there should appear a color. On right selection color should be green and on wrong selection color should be red. That's all i want. The checkanswer() function i pasted here works fine with MaterialButton. But i want to use this same functionality with RadioButtons..

Comment: I added Material Button Code in question.

Comment: I am sorry but can you drop the Page code (the page with the material button) so I understand fully